# Symbol with Subscript but no quotes in it!

Tags: output-formatting, symbols

If I use the following function to define me a fancy subscript:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[SubscriptBox["_", "_"]]]

SetAttributes[fancySubscript,HoldFirst]

fancySubscript[var_Symbol, tag_String, index_Integer] /;
  Not[ValueQ[var]] := Subscript[var, tag <> ToString[index]]

fancySubscript[var_Symbol, tags : {_String ..}, index_Integer] /; 
  Not[ValueQ[var]] := fancySubscript[var, #, index] & /@ tags

fancySubscript[var_Symbol, tags : {_String ..}, indices : {_Integer ..}] /; 
  Not[ValueQ[var]] := fancySubscript[var, tags, #] & /@ indices
```

I can use the following now:

```
fancySubscript[b, {"b"}, Range@3]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  b_{\text{b1}} \\
>  b_{\text{b2}} \\
>  b_{\text{b3}}  \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

With the notation module by symbolizing the subscripts: the values are now :

```
b\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]DoubleQuote\[UnderBracket]b1\[UnderBracket]DoubleQuote
```

**1. Problem**
But when I want to refer to such a variable in the list above and write with the shortcuts in a cell by typing <kbd>b</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> then <kbd>1</kbd>.

**The variable is a new symbol because i did not use Quotes ""**

```
b\[UnderBracket]Subscript\[UnderBracket]b1
```

How can we circumvent this that I can still write all variables in the cell and they are parsed and interpreted as the one defined in the `fancySubscript` command?

It is not so easy because, when I would use something like this:

```
fancySubscript[b, {b}, Range@3]
```

I would get an infinite loop, because it is no more a string, hm...

**2. Problem:**

I cannot assign it back to the variable b:

```
 b=fancySubscript[b, {"b"}, Range@3]
```

This gives an infinite loop, but when I try this:

```
btemp=fancySubscript[b, {"b"}, Range@3]
b=btemp
```

This should work, and not give an inifinte loop, because btemp contains the new defined symbols and they should then be assigned to `b` again, but also here mathematica trys to run a recursion which I dont understand??