# Using both subscripted and non-subscripted variables in an equation

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, variable-definitions, symbols, custom-notation

I'm getting started with Mathematica, as I have been using Maple in the past. Is it possible to define two variables $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ and then still use $\alpha$ as a parameter of a function and, for example, plot it.

$\alpha_1:=5$
$\alpha_2:=10$

$a:=\sum_{i=1}^{2}\alpha_i \cdot \alpha$

```
Plot[a,{α,0,10}]
```

I have found that I have to use a *different variable*, such as $\tilde{\alpha}$ for that to work. Any way around that?

On a side note, is it possible to have Mathematica treat an expression such as $a_b$ as *one variable*, but still understand subscripts on other defined variables such as $a_1, a_2, …$? I understand that the `Symbolize` package is used for that, but did not quite get how to symbolize only specific expressions.

I apologize for my lack of deeper understanding in Mathematica, but that's what you get when you use something as soothing to the eye as Maple ;)

Comment: Related or duplicate: [(20195)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20195/121), [(22376)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22376/121), [(36952)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36952/121), [(158447)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/158447/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, it is best not to use the same variable inside and outside of [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript). However, nothing is stopping you from using a string inside of [`Subscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subscript):

```
Subscript["α", 1] = 5;
Subscript["α", 2] = 10;

a := Sum[Subscript["α", i] α, {i, 2}]

Plot[a, {α, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Can you explain why you need to treat $a_b$ as one variable?

Comment: It is a mostly readability - "ab" would of course work as a variable, but ultimately I want to print my worksheets and then have them look nice. I've been using the Palettes (Basic Math Assistant) for graphical fractions etc. for that very purpose.
Am I confusing Mathematica too much with LaTeX?

Comment: @Wasserwaage In what context does `Subscript[a, b]` (or `Subscript["a", "b"]`) not work as a variable?

Comment: It works, I am just trying to keep the potential for errors in my worksheet to a minimum - and defining Subscript[a,b] would have seemed like a sensible way to do that. Thanks!